# PDF fields not displaying correct output until clicked

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have tried using iText as well as PDFBox for PDF form filling with dynamic values. I'm using embedded fonts. This works fine for english language. But for marathi language when PDF gets generated pdf fields shows unexpected output, but when fields are clicked it shows required output. Why output is getting changed?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A3dFSHM9r3fLtRHUpFwlCDa6QOm5n-m8

```
    String unicodeFontPath = "templates/font/FreeSans.ttf";
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper filledOutForm = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields fields = filledOutForm.getAcroFields();
    BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont(unicodeFontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    fields.setFieldProperty("Given Name Text Box", "textfont", unicode, null);
    fields.setField("Given Name Text Box", emp.getName());
```

Comment: You are using an old version of iText that doesn't support the Marathi language. You need at least iText 7 **and the closed source pdfCalligraph add-on.** There is no open source support for Marathi (not in iText, not in another library).

Comment: PDFBox label removed, you didn't show any PDFBox code. We can't do it either, although we may in the future. Currently somebody is working on Bengali, and if that works, we'll try to support other languages too.